# question regarding select query

Tags: mysql

Please note, I am a beginner with all of this.

I am trying to select all the group ids of which a user_id attached to.

so the table I am querying has structure of:

group_id | user_id

currently it just grabs one group ID where the user ID is attached.

here is my query:

```
$ID = $_SESSION['myuserid'];

$get_group = mysql_query("SELECT group_id FROM group_association_tb WHERE user_id = $ID");

$groups = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_group);
```

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$get_group` is a MySql result set, so you will need to loop through it to get all the `group_id` entries:

```
$groups = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_group)) {
    $groups[] = $row["group_id"];
}
```

now the `$groups` array will hold all of your group ids.